# How substitution is used in second order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to determine how the equation was simplified which was shown (not completely) in textbook on ordinary differential equations.

The following equation,

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 Y}{d x^2} + Y(aY^{2} + b)^{-2}\frac{dY}{dx}+Y=0
 \label{1}
\end{equation}

can be simplified by assuming that

\begin{equation}
w=\frac{dY}{dx}
 \label{2}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
z=-\frac{1}{2}Y^{2}
 \label{3}
\end{equation}

then the equation simplifies to Abel equation form which is

\begin{equation}
\frac{dw}{dz}w + (-2az + b)^{-2}w+1=0
 \label{4}
\end{equation}

Here is my attempt

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 Y}{d x^2} + Y(aY^{2} + b)^{-2}\frac{dY}{dx}+Y=0
 \label{}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 Y}{d x^2}\frac{1}{Y} + (aY^{2} + b)^{-2}\frac{dY}{dx}+1=0
 \label{}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 Y}{d x^2}\frac{1}{Y} + (aY^{2} + b)^{-2}w+1=0
 \label{}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 Y}{d x^2}\frac{1}{Y} + (-2az + b)^{-2}w+1=0
 \label{}
\end{equation}
I am stuck with second derivative of Y and convert it into first derivative w with respect to z

Comment: By the chain rule, 

\begin{align} \frac{dw}{dz} &= \frac{dw}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dz} \\ &= \frac{dw}{dx} \cdot \frac{1}{\frac{dz}{dx}} \\ &= \frac{dw}{dx} \cdot \frac{1}{-Y \cdot \frac{dY}{dx}} \\ &= \frac{dw}{dx} \cdot \frac{1}{-w \cdot Y} \\ \implies -w \frac{dw}{dz} &= \frac{dw}{dx} \cdot \frac{1}{Y} \\ &= \frac{d^{2}Y}{dx^{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{Y} \end{align}

so I believe there is a sign error somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  That solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=\dfrac{dY}{dx}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^2Y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{dw}{dx}=\dfrac{dw}{dY}\dfrac{dY}{dx}=w\dfrac{dw}{dY}$

$\therefore w\dfrac{dw}{dY}+Y(aY^2+b)^{-2}w+Y=0$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dY}=-\dfrac{Yw}{(aY^2+b)^2}-Y$

Let $z=-\dfrac{Y^2}{2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dw}{dY}=\dfrac{dw}{dz}\dfrac{dz}{dY}=-Y\dfrac{dw}{dz}$

$\therefore-Yw\dfrac{dw}{dz}=-\dfrac{Yw}{(aY^2+b)^2}-Y$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dz}=\dfrac{w}{(-2az+b)^2}+1$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dz}=\dfrac{w}{(2az-b)^2}+1$

Let $s=-\dfrac{1}{2a(2az-b)}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dw}{dz}=\dfrac{dw}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{dz}=\dfrac{1}{(2az-b)^2}\dfrac{dw}{ds}=4a^2s^2\dfrac{dw}{ds}$

$\therefore4a^2s^2w\dfrac{dw}{ds}=4a^2s^2w+1$

$w\dfrac{dw}{ds}=w+\dfrac{1}{4a^2s^2}$

And luckily we can find its general solution in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=136.